# How to format a number into thousands, millions and billions with dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get a number converted into something like this: 12K, 1.5M, 4.2B from a normal number like: 134900.

Comment: Good that you found a way to do it. Instead of posting answer like this, it is suggested to ask a question and post this answer to it. This way it will appear in searches properly.

Comment: Thanks @AbhilashChandran i changed it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a minimalist function, of course you'll have to add validation code to verify if the number is valid before executing the function. Otherwise Enjoy ...

```
void main() {
      double num = 1250;

      var myNumber = k_m_b_generator(num);

      print(myNumber);
    }

    String k_m_b_generator(num) {
      if (num > 999 && num < 99999) {
        return "${(num / 1000).toStringAsFixed(1)} K";
      } else if (num > 99999 && num < 999999) {
        return "${(num / 1000).toStringAsFixed(0)} K";
      } else if (num > 999999 && num < 999999999) {
        return "${(num / 1000000).toStringAsFixed(1)} M";
      } else if (num > 999999999) {
        return "${(num / 1000000000).toStringAsFixed(1)} B";
      } else {
        return num.toString();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use flutter's [NumberFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) class with the [compact](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.compact.html) function.

```
formatNumber(dynamic myNumber) {
    // Convert number into a string if it was not a string previously
    String stringNumber = myNumber.toString();

    // Convert number into double to be formatted.
    // Default to zero if unable to do so
    double doubleNumber = double.tryParse(stringNumber) ?? 0;

    // Set number format to use
    NumberFormat numberFormat = new NumberFormat.compact();

    return numberFormat.format(doubleNumber);
}
```

Comment: Not showing k if not set locale

Answer (score 6):

The answer is not entirely correct. If you test it, you will see what i meant. Base on the answer above, I created this solution:

```
String numberFormat(int n) {
  String num = n.toString();
  int len = num.length;

  if (n >= 1000 && n < 1000000) {
    return num.substring(0, len - 3) + '.' + num.substring(len - 3, 1 + (len - 3)) + 'k';
  } else if (n >= 1000000 && n < 1000000000) {
    return num.substring(0, len - 6) + '.' + num.substring(len - 6, 1 + (len - 6)) + 'm';
  } else if (n > 1000000000) {
    return num.substring(0, len - 9) + '.' + num.substring(len - 9, 1 + (len - 9)) + 'b';
  } else {
    return num.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Solution:**

**Step 1:** Go to your flutter project's root & install the dart package [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) by executing on your terminal:

```
dart pub add intl
```

Or..

```
flutter pub add intl
```

**Step 2:** Type on your terminal:

```
dart pub get
```

Or...

```
flutter pub get
```

...or simply click on "*Pub get*" on your Android Studio IDE, pubspec.yaml file

**Step # 3:** Usage:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
.
.
.
final int value = 21600478; 
final formatter = NumberFormat.compact(locale: "en_US", explicitSign: false);
print(formatter.format(value));
.
.
.
```

**Result on your Terminal:**

[image]

**Code Example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_udemy_092_toktik/domain/entities/video_post.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class VideoButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final VideoPost videoPost;

  const VideoButtons({super.key, required this.videoPost});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _CustomIconButton(
          value: videoPost.likes,
          iconData: Icons.favorite,
          iconColor: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        _CustomIconButton(
          value: videoPost.views,
          iconData: Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _CustomIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  final IconData iconData;
  final Color iconColor;

  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  const _CustomIconButton({super.key, required this.value, required this.iconData, this.iconColor = Colors.white, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final formatter = NumberFormat.compact(locale: "en_US", explicitSign: false);

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          disabledColor: iconColor,
          icon: Icon(
            iconData,
            size: 30,
          ),
          color: iconColor,
        ),
        Text(
          formatter.format(value),
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Visual Result:**

[image]